# screen extensions to vt52

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-console

The documentation for the [vt52](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/terminal/vt52/EK-VT5X-OP-001_DECscope_Users_Manual_Mar77.pdf) terminal does not include the codes transmitted for
CTRL+ something, ALT+ something (clearly: they did not exist).
screen launched in vt52 mode sends some keys. For instance,
CTRL-C is 0x03, CTRL-Z is 0x1A, and ALT seems to prefix 0x1B to anything.
Is there any standard regulating this behavior/is it documented somewhere?

Comment: this may help https://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/

Comment: thanks for the link, howeve  that does not seem to be the used extension (simplest difference: there's no alt key)